# Query error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Does anyone know why my mySQL query gets this error? SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

```
try {
                                $sql = "UPDATE kunder SET fname=?, ename=?, user=? WHERE id = :id";
                                $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION["user_id"]);
                                $data = array($fname, $ename, $user);
                                $stmt->execute($data);
                            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                            }
```

Comment: You're using '?' to indicate positional parameters, and you're also using ':id' to indicate a named parameter.  I suggest you choose one or the other

Comment: Also there is an explicit call to `bindParam()` and also passing an array of parameter values to `execute()`. Use one method or the other. My habit is to pass values to `execute()` in all cases, unless I need to bind parameters by reference for multiple executions.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $sql = 'UPDATE kunder SET ' .
        'fname=:fname,' .
        'ename=:ename,' .
        'user=:user ' .
        'WHERE id = :id';
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
    $data = array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'ename' => $ename,
        'user' => $user,
        'id' => $_SESSION["user_id"],
    );
    $stmt->execute($data);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```